# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import module from the same package

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I have an import problem which is probably obvious, but I'm kind of stuck, so I will ask here, maybe you will see it immediately:

files structure:

```
foobar_package/
    __init__.py
    classes.py
    enums.py
```

`classes.py:`

```py
import enums

class Foo:
   ...
```

I want Foo class to be importable directly from the package:
Instead of:

```py
from foobar_package.classes import Foo
```

I want to be able to write:

```py
from foobar_package import Foo
```

So I edited my **init**.py:
`__init__.py:`

```py
from .classes import *
```

The problem is, when do:

```py
import foobar_package
```

I get:

```
  File "foobar_package/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .classes import *
  File "foobar_package/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    import enums
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enums'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you read [Relative Imports for the Billionth Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/16775594)?

Comment: Hmm, no, seems useful. I will read it and try to solve the problem then, thanks.